# Execute if statement only after other processes in function are complete (async/await/promises vs observable)

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, observable

In `Angular 6`, I'm using the function `save()` whenever a user enters a new record into a table on our app.

Within `save()` we check for two things:
1. 'front end' validation errors AKA *'you cant enter a price in the 'Price' column if the 'Item' column is empty'*. In this case, the data is never sent to the database.
2. 'back end' errors AKA user attempts to enter a duplicate record. This does try to POST to database via our service, but the database returns an error (database cant accept records where every column is a duplicate).

Once these checks are complete, I have two variables `frontendChecked` and `backendChecked` which I set to 'true'.

At the end of `save()`, I'm (incorrectly) attempting to do something once the above two processes are complete by using an `if statement` to check if these two variables are true. This `if statement` never runs due to the asynchronous nature of our backend errors.

**myComponent.ts:**

```
save() {

    var frontendChecked = false;
    var backendChecked = false;

    //----------- check for front end errors -----------//
   for(var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
      // check for front end errors here
      if( i === records.length - 1) {
          frontendChecked = true;
      }
   }

   //----------- check for backend errors (forkjoin is an observable in our service which returns asynchronously - we subscribe to it here) -----------//
   this.myService.forkJoin(myArray)
   .subscribe(
       data => { 
           for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
               //check for backend errors here
               if( i === records.length - 1) {
                   backendChecked = true;
               }
           }
       }
   );

   //----------- this if statement never runs because backendChecked is not finished in time -----------//
   if (frontendChecked && backendChecked) {
       // I need to do these things last
   }

}
```

How can I ensure that my if statement at the end of `save()` actually runs once both of those variables have been set? I've been looking into `async/await` with promises, and also observables. The result of `this.myService.forkJoin` is actually derived from us subscribing to the observable `forkJoin`, which is throwing me off a bit. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't. Put the final `if` block inside the callback passed to subscribe, right after the for loop.

Comment: In the code sample above your front end check is already complete before you call your service, Therefore, you could wrap you service in an if(frontendChecked) and only call it when the front end check was successful. Then you know both checks have happened in the subscribe to your service call and can just do the check there. The forkJoin should already ensure that all service calls are complete if there are multiple instances although that is a different syntax that I typically use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
this.myService.forkJoin(myArray)
   .subscribe(
       data => { 
           for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
               //check for backend errors here
               if( i === records.length - 1) {
                   backendChecked = true;
               }
           }
           if (frontendChecked) {
              // I need to do these things last
           }
       }
   );
```